# How do I start slui.exe in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to run `Process.Start("C:\Windows\system32\slui.exe", " 3")` after the user clicks a button. Unfortunately the application insists that the file does not exist - even when it is run with admin rights.

I know the file exists however since I can copy the path and execute the desired program from windows explorer. So what am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: does it throws FileNotFoundException?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: It throws a System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception with the message "The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ProcessStartInfo class to specify the working directory of the application that you want to start and its arguments

```
Dim pi = new ProcessStartInfo()
pi.FileName = "slui.exe"
pi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
pi.Arguments = "3"
Process.Start(pi)
```

Comment: Confirmed, how strange. Manually works, inside a progran not. I will try to find some information about this